# O que significa a palavra "fila"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Para os Brasileiros, `fila` significa uma série de pessoas, esperando por algo.

Gostaria de saber se em Portugal tem o mesmo significado?

Comment: +1 por colocar a questão

Comment: É só dar uma olhada no Priberam: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fila Porqué essa pregunta tem 10 pontos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tem o mesmo significado e até onde sei é um termo muito usado por lá.

Também é usado o termo bicha que tem uma outra conotação também. É um termo considerado pejorativo para se referir a homossexuais masculinos. Muito usado<sup>1</sup> neste contexto no Brasil mas também usado em menor escala em Portugal.

Ao contrário da crença popular entre os brasileiros (provavelmente criada por humoristas), bicha não é usada pelo portugueses exaustivamente no lugar de fila. É um sinônimo informal apenas, eles entendem fila perfeitamente tal qual os brasileiros entendem.

E fila significa uma sequência de objetos onde o primeiro a entrar na sequência será o primeiro a ser retirado. Muitas vezes isto se refere a pessoas, mas nem sempre.

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado :)

[Dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fila).

1. Ou era no tempo que o politicamente correto não dominava a sociedade. Ainda é bastante usado, mas em certos círculos, ficou complicado usar o termo.

Comment: Não está errado. ;)

Comment: Vê a minha resposta na pergunta relacionada. Atualmente, "bicha não é usada pelo portugueses exaustivamente no lugar de fila" . mas antigamente era.

Comment: Bicha era a expressão mais usada até há uns 15-20 anos.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @bigown está correta, mas eu vivi diretamente as aventura da *bicha* e *fila* em Portugal, e posso dar mais informação. Atualmente *bicha* e *fila* são em Portugal as palavras com o significado de uma série de pessoas ou veículos atrás uns dos outros à espera de poderem avançar por ordem. Mas *bicha* é muito pouco usado. Mas nem sempre foi assim.

Até aos finais dos anos oitenta *bicha* era a única palavra usada com esse sentido. *Fila* designava apenas um conjunto de coisas ou pessoas lado a lado, como um fila de cadeiras num teatro, ou de árvores num pomar. O Dicionário Lello Universal, publicado em 1992, não dá outro signifcado a *fila* (dentro dos significados que aqui nos interessam), apesar de dar grande destaque à cultura brasileira na sua parte enciclopédica. Chamava-se no entanto *fila de espera* a uma bicha virtual, pessoas que seriam chamadas por ordem, por exemplo num consultório médico, mas que podia estar sentadas na sala de espera onde lhes apetecesse.

Mesmo no fim dos anos oitenta comecei a ver *fila* ser usado com o significado de bicha na comunicação social. Foi também nessa altura que se começou a ouvir *bicha* com o significado de homossexual.

Em meados dos anos noventa já quase toda a gente usava exclusivamente *fila* em vez de *bicha.* É impossível que se tenham esquecido de *bicha.* Tenho a ideia que na cabeça de muita gente *bicha* passou a ser do tipo de palavras que camponeses diziam lá na terrinha e que uma pessoa educada não deveria dizer. Este episódio é revelador. Passou-se entre 1995 e 1997. Estava eu numa bicha na estação de correios, e chega uma senhora, com aspeto e maneiras de pessoa educada, e diz-me qualquer coisa como "O senhor é o último da bicha? Bicha, não. Fila."

E pronto, aqui está a história verídica de como uma palavra perfeitamente legítima foi praticamente aniquilada, ao que parece, por uma coligação diabólica de ignorância e preconceito.