# "Bichas" ou "filas"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Em Portugal usa-se muito o termo "bicha" e o termo "fila" para indicar um aglomerado de pessoas, alinhadas, à espera da sua vez para alguma coisa.

É certo dizer-se **bicha**? E **fila**?

Quando utilizar uma e outra?

Comment: Só não use a primeira no Brasil. De resto acho que é tranquilo.

Comment: @LucasMotta aqui também tem esse significado. ;)

Comment: Uma resposta relacionada: [O que significa a palavra “fila”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/121/156)

Comment: Mas então, a resposta à [outra pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/121/156) não é suficiente?

Comment: Não é duplicata porque não explica a diferença entre elas, e não são sinónimos. São perguntas bem diferentes.

Comment: @JorgeB. é suficiente que a pergunta duplicada "se reduza" a outra cuja resposta também esclarece a dúvida de quem passaria por esta pergunta. Portanto: o que é que falta [nesta resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/121/84) que não serviria para responder também a esta pergunta?

Comment: E para reforçar o meu argumento, surgiu agora uma resposta que não acrescenta nada a aquilo que já foi dito na resposta da outra pergunta.

Comment: Se a resposta for editada e colocada a diferença das duas sim. Eu amanhã faço uma resposta se esta não se fechar

Comment: Concordo com @E_net4, votando para fechar.

Comment: @JorgeB. A resposta daquela pergunta também responde a sua pergunta. A resposta além de explicar o significado de fila, ainda faz uma comparação com bicha, dizendo que é um termo informal e também com outra conotação.

Comment: BrunoLopes não é isso, é o que estou a tentar dizer. É que não é um termo informal. Senão não tinha feito a pergunta. Que já tinha visto a outra. Devia era ter referenciado a outra. Amanhã respondo a isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Então não seria melhor criar uma resposta para aquela pergunta esclarecendo esses pontos que você citou?

Comment: @BrunoLopes já criei uma resposta. Não sei se ela se enquadra na outra pergunta...

Comment: **@todos** : não importa se é duplicata. *Duplicata é bom!* . . . . A outra pergunta não tem "bicha" no título.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu levantei esta questão, mesmo havendo [esta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/114/o-que-significa-a-palavra-fila), porque em Portugal tem sido debatido o significado de **bicha** e de **fila**.

Fala-se que **bicha** será usada para, e passo a citar, *designar uma aglomeração de indivíduos ou objetos, **não necessariamente reta**, por vezes algo sinuosa e anárquica, e **parada** ou quase (bicha de espera, bicha de trânsito)*

E que **fila** será usada *para designar uma aglomeração de pessoas ou objetos em **linha mais ou menos reta** e em **movimento** (trânsito em duas filas)*

---

Eu também sempre ouvi esta forma de dizer, é **bicha** quando está parada

> Temos uma bicha de carros parada

E **fila** quando está em andamento

> Temos duas filas de transito nesta Auto Estrada

---

Aqui temos uma resposta de um pesquisador sobre a nossa língua:

> No «Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa», de Cândido de Figueiredo, editado em 1939 (Bertrand), bicha é associada a «qualquer objeto que, pelo seu feitio ou movimento sinuoso, dá ideia de um réptil». Entre outros sentidos, Cândido de Figueiredo atribui-lhe o de «fileira de pessoas, umas atrás das outras». Fila, na mesma obra e no significado que aqui nos interessa, é uma «série de coisas (animais ou pessoas) dispostas em linha reta. Enfiada; fileira: uma fila de cadeiras.» Nos dicionários mais recentes que consultei, seguem-se, no essencial, estas indicações.

Fonte [Bichas ou filas?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/bichas-ou-filas/219)

---

Há quem diga que o segundo sentido da palavra **bicha** (pejorativo) veio mesmo do Brasil através das telenovelas. Há quem diga que já se dizia na alta sociedade há alguns anos. Mas, na verdade, não é assim tão usado no dia-a-dia, em Portugal.

De notar também que hoje em dia o termo **bicha** (de carros) é quase considerado como calão ou gíria (não confundir com baixo calão). Mas é ainda amplamente usada, era capaz de dizer que é mais usada do que **fila**.

Comment: 1+, ótima resposta. Aee, te livrei do número do mal! XD Brincadeiras à parte, baseando-se nisso, então a resposta daquela outra pergunta está errada, porque pelo que se vê não são sinônimos, são apenas palavras com significados parecidos.

Comment: @BrunoLopes até tirei print ontem da minha reputação :D

Comment: @BrunoLopes mas há um problema, as definições no dicionário são muito subjetivas. Não são objetivas. O problema está mesmo ai. Senão eu tinha respondido na outra pergunta.

Comment: *"veio mesmo do Brasil através das telenovelas"* {{citation needed}} . . . . . . achei duas referências interessantes: [bicha | Origem Da Palavra](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/bicha/) e [Bicha - Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/bicha/), mas nada de telenovela...

Comment: @brasofilo que achas assim?

Comment: [Tudo sobre as bichas. :)](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/bicha)

Comment: @JorgeB. Não entendo,,,(?) "que acho assim" o quê?

Comment: @brasofilo a resposta, alterei a, que achas dela assim?

Comment: @tchrist Eu desconfio que a sacanagem brasileira converteu (ou perverteu) a palavra portuguesa por conta da "fila de gente uma atrás da outra" ;)

Comment: oh, sorry, acabo de instalar a App do Stack, as coisas ainda não são óbvias :) Gostei mucho, é legal isso da sinuosidade e da reta. Precisamos de algum senhor de 80 anos que saiba dizer "ah, isso começou no Brasil em mil novecentos e batatinha"... Pô, vamos caçar uns acadêmicos brazukas e portugas pra dar pitaco aqui ;)

Comment: Dar pitaco? Mandar bitaites!